# Nginx remove URL path and place it as a query parameter

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

I have a URL like so: `https://example.org/v2?product=lifesum` and I need to rewrite it to be: `https://example.org?version=v2&product=lifesum`. The URL may have more or less query params, so I need to keep all of those. Also, the `/v2` may actually not be present, so I need to handle those cases. Here are some examples of how this should be rewritten:

- `https://example.org/v2?product=lifesum` ->
  `https://example.org?version=v2&product=lifesum`
- `https://example.org?product=lifesum` ->
  `https://example.org?product=lifesum`
- `https://example.org/v13/foo/bar?product=lifesum` -> `https://example.org/foo/bar?version=v13&product=lifesum`
- `https://example.org/v1113` -> `https://example.org?version=v1113`
- `https://example.org` -> `https://example.org`

Here is what I have tried so far, but it is not working:

```
# HTTP Server
    server {
        # port to listen on. Can also be set to an IP:PORT
        listen 8080;

        # This is my attempt to match and rewrite
        location ~* (\/v\d+) {
            rewrite (\/v\d+) /?api_version=$1 break;
        }

        location = / {
            # I have also tried this rewrite but iit is not working either
            rewrite (\/v\d+) /?api_version=$1 break;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
```

**NOTE:** This is a Single Page Application, if that helps.

Comment: Try: `rewrite ^/(v\d+)(?:/(.*))?$ /$2?version=$1 redirect;`

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks for your help! Should that go in the `location ~*` block or the `location = /` block or directly under the `server` block?

Comment: @RichardSmith That is soooooo close. Here is the URL it lands on: `http://example.com:8080//getting-started?version=v2&product=life`. The only issue is that it is adding an extra `/` and the port number. That is with the `rewrite` placed in the `location ~*` block.

Comment: I don't see `//` when I test it. Did you use my regular expression exactly as written? The `rewrite` can go in the `server` block or a matching `location` block. The `location = /` block will not work as it only matches the URI `/`. The port number is included unless you use [`port_in_redirect off;`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#port_in_redirect).

Comment: @RichardSmith I got it, thanks! You want to make that the answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To meet all of your requirements, you will need to capture that part of the URI which follows the version string.

For example:

```
rewrite ^/(v\d+)(?:/(.*))?$ /$2?version=$1 redirect;
```

The `redirect` flag causes Nginx to use an external redirect with a 302 status (see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details). An external redirect is necessary for the SPA to see the new URI.

The `rewrite` statement can be placed in the outer `server` block or within a `location` block that matches the original URI (for example: `location ~* ^/v\d`).

To avoid Nginx adding a port number to the redirected URI, use:

```
port_in_redirect off;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#port_in_redirect) for details.